# Using XDocument and XElement how do I add a XAttribute and a value to XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to replicate:

```
    <gcf>
        <cbxDecOnly Type="Boolean">False</cbxDecOnly>
        <cbxFormName Type="String" />
        <txtCustomerCellPhonePart2 Type="String">5236</txtCustomerCellPhonePart2>
        <txtCustomerCellPhonePart1 Type="String">533</txtCustomerCellPhonePart1>
        ....
    </gcf>
```

so far I have:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement("gcf",
    new XElement("cbxDecOnly", new XAttribute("Type", "Boolean")),
    new XElement("cbxFormName", oGSFE.TextBoxClientName),
    new XElement("txtCustomerCellPhonePart2", oGSFE.TextBoxDealSearch),
    new XElement("txtCustomerCellPhonePart1 ", oGSFE.DropDownListFIManager)
                )
            );
```

what I don't know is how to add a XAttribute and a value at the same time to the XML element `<cbxDecOnly Type="Boolean">False</cbxDecOnly>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same way you provide the value for your `txtCustomerCellPhonePart2` etc nodes - by including the string value as one of the [element's `params content[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302741(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement("gcf",
    new XElement("cbxDecOnly", "False", new XAttribute("Type", "Boolean")),
    new XElement("cbxFormName", oGSFE.TextBoxClientName),
    new XElement("txtCustomerCellPhonePart2", oGSFE.TextBoxDealSearch),
    new XElement("txtCustomerCellPhonePart1", oGSFE.DropDownListFIManager)
    )
);
```

Any values of type `string` provided in `content[]` will be merged into the element's value, any values of type `XAttribute` will create attributes and any values of type `XElement` will become the children.